# Remove the first link on the second tr element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have this HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"> Some text </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Some text </td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="btn btn-link" href="/pingenieros/web/app_dev.php/admin/pi/proyecto/proyectos/create"><i class="icon-plus"></i>New</a>
                <a class="btn btn-link" href="/pingenieros/web/app_dev.php/admin/pi/proyecto/proyectos/list"><i class="icon-list"></i> List</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     ... many others tr ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to remove using jQuery the first `a` element in the second `tr` meaning the one with `New` text, any advice?

Note: My bad a made a typo

Comment: _"the one with Add text"_ Add text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**it has a `div` parent**

so it doesn't really matter that it's in a `td`...

```
$('.btn-group:eq(0) a:eq(0)').remove();
```

or to repeat for all .btn-group:

```
$('.btn-group a:eq(0)').remove();
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/TFSem/

Answer (score 5):

Try

Shortest code

```
$('tr:eq(1) a.btn-link:first').remove();
```

---

```
$('tr:eq(1) a:first').remove();
```

---

```
$('tr:eq(1) a:contains("New")').first().remove();
```

---

For exact match remove

```
$('tr:eq(1) a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === 'New';
}).first().remove();
```

Reference

[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

[:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

[.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: Every time that you say `td` here i think you mean `tr`